# Why does VB6 MkDir command throw error 75 on other machines but not on mine?

Tags: vb6, mkdir

My VB6 program uses Mkdir to create a folder after first confirming that the folder doesn't exist, using this couldn't-be-simpler code:

```
If LenB(Dir$(ImportFolder & "\" & UuidPartOfImportFolderName, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
  MkDir ImportFolder & "\" & sIECommon2.gstrUniqueImportUuid
End If
```

When I run this code in my own development environment, from inside the IDE, or even run the .exe on my local machine, it works perfectly--the folder gets created as expected and other files are then successfully created in it.

But when I build the executable and install it on another machine, the Mkdir command throws the error 'Error 75: Path/File Access error'.  (I narrowed it down to this command by putting a MsgBox command immediately before and after it--the one before gets displayed, but the one after does not.)

The default permissions on a folder created using Mkdir are rwx for everyone, according to my research ...so why would it throw the error on other machines and not on mine?

Or maybe it has nothing to do with what machine it's running on--I just had no other theories.  The other weird thing is that this program has used MkDir in other places for years; I've just added this new one when I added additional functionality.

Thank you--looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Hard to say unless you tell us what ImportFolder is.  However I don't know where you got the idea making a folder sets the security on it to anything besides whatever its parent folder has as inherited security for child objects.  Lots of the "common" special folders have owner security for example.

Comment: ImportFolder is:
 
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Application Data\CompanyName\ProductName\Import

Comment: It would be ok if the security on the newly-created folder were inherited from the parent, because it's in the user's profile.  Yet the user running this program gets the error.

Comment: You are checking for `FolderX` but creating `FolderY` which could already be preset. Also make sure that parent folder exists (C:\...\ProductName\Import)

Comment: What operating systems are you running on the two machines? I'd be willing to bet that the one it works on is running Windows XP, and the one it *doesn't* work on has either Vista or 7.

Comment: More than likely a permissions problem related to Windows 7 or Vista as mentioned above. If it is Windows 7 or Vista - try running the application as administrator (or running vb6.exe as administrator if you want to run in the IDE) and see if the problem disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that WQW's answer is what's happening, but, you might want to verify that the two machines are running the same version of teh VB6 runtimes (MSVBVM6.dll). There are several versions. It's a long shot but one might behave slightly differently than another.

But again, I kind of doubt that, I suspect the two folder names you're working with aren't exactly the same.

Comment: We finally resolved the problem by replacing the use of MkDir with this:

      Dim objDir As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
      objDir.CreateFolder ImportFolder & "\" & UuidPartOfImportFolderName

Thank you all for your responses.